# sequelize.js custom validator, check for unique username / password

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Imagine I have defined the following custom validator function:

```
isUnique: function () { // This works as expected
  throw new Error({error:[{message:'Email address already in use!'}]});
}
```

However, when I attempt to query the DB I run into problems:

```
isUnique: function (email) { // This doesn't work
  var User = seqeulize.import('/path/to/user/model');

  User.find({where:{email: email}})
    .success(function () { // This gets called
      throw new Error({error:[{message:'Email address already in use!'}]});  // But this isn't triggering a validation error.
    });
}
```

How can I query the ORM in a custom validator and trigger a validation error based on the response from the ORM?

Comment: well that won't work, you can try to simple run `.find()` and in callback manipulate the result of query and call `response.render` or anything else to send a message to user.

Comment: Seriously!?  I'm trying to program to the Sequelize interface rather than a solid implementation.  Why doesn't the above work?  I can only imagine that .find is catching the error somewhere?

Comment: Just to clarify, User.find({where:{email: email}}).success() works perfectly (as specified in the Sequelize docs).  The problem is that Sequelize is not catching the Error, or the error is being caught else where.

Comment: as far as i know `User.find()` returns an event, it will throw an error when event is emitted, so calling the `isUnique("example@example.com")`, and even try `try..catch` won't do it.

Comment: Ok, looks like I have a lot of work to do to get Sequelize into shape.  It's nowhere near as robust as I had been led to believe...

Comment: The error is thrown in the callback, so it never will occur in the isUnique function. Solution would be to make validation asyncroniously. Sadly sequelize currently does not allow this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can verify if the email already exists like that:

```
email: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    isEmail:true
  },
  unique: {
      args: true,
      msg: 'Email address already in use!'
  }
}
```

Comment: This! I don't understand why the others need to run a `user.find` before insert.

Comment: @BaNz yes you can do this & obviously its better, but if you have auto increment value in the table then if your insert query fails because of unique violation then also your auto increment id will increase, yes its the way any SQL works.

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to use `unique` property of the column `email` (i.e. not  as a property of your `validate` object.)  [The docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)  say that `attributes.column.unique` can have value of `String | Boolean` ; but your value is an *object* (not String or Boolean) whose value is : ` { args: true, msg : '...' }` . That value looks like how you would use `unique` if you added it to the `validate` object; but you have `unique` directly on the `email` (aka column) object...

Comment: The `unique` parameter accepts a object if it have `args` as a 'String' or a 'Boolean' value. The msg attribute is used as a validation message.

Comment: I've changed this to the accepted answer. It was answered almost 4 years after the original question and I only just noticed it.

Comment: 2021 and this is not working as mentionere here. Using Sequelize 6.3.3

Comment: @NeerajGulia Working just fine for me on 6.6.5

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simplified sample of a functioning `isUnique` validation callback (works as of SequelizeJS v2.0.0). I added comments to explain the important bits:

```
var UserModel = sequelize.define('User', {

    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            isUnique: function(value, next) {

                UserModel.find({
                    where: {email: value},
                    attributes: ['id']
                })
                    .done(function(error, user) {

                        if (error)
                            // Some unexpected error occured with the find method.
                            return next(error);

                        if (user)
                            // We found a user with this email address.
                            // Pass the error to the next method.
                            return next('Email address already in use!');

                        // If we got this far, the email address hasn't been used yet.
                        // Call next with no arguments when validation is successful.
                        next();

                    });

            }
        }
    }

});

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Answer (score 11):

With Sequelize 2.0, you need to catch Validation Errors.

First, define the User Model with a custom validator:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User',
    {
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            validate: {
                isUnique: function (value, next) {
                    var self = this;
                    User.find({where: {email: value}})
                        .then(function (user) {
                            // reject if a different user wants to use the same email
                            if (user && self.id !== user.id) {
                                return next('Email already in use!');
                            }
                            return next();
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        });
                }
            }
        },
        other_field: Sequelize.STRING
    });

module.exports = User;
```

Then, in the controller, catch any Validation Errors:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    User = require('./path/to/User.model');

exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var allowedKeys = ['email', 'other_field'];
    var attributes = _.pick(req.body, allowedKeys);
    User.create(attributes)
        .then(function (user) {
            res.json(user);
        })
        .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
            // respond with validation errors
            return res.status(422).send(err.errors);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // every other error
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: err.message
            });
        });
```

Comment: thanks you for answer. I am using above approach for my query but I am unable to catch validation errors on my controller. As I am using await User.create() instead of User.create().then(). I have tried nesting User.create() in try block and catching errors in catch block but I am unable to get those validation errors inside catch block. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Success callback is called even if no user is found. You have to check if the function passes a user as an argument:

```
isUnique: function (email) {
  var User = seqeulize.import('/path/to/user/model');

  User.find({where:{email: email}})
    .success(function (u) { // This gets called
      if(u){
        throw new Error({error:[{message:'Email address already in use!'}]});  // But this isn't triggering a validation error.
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am troubled by the fact that the code in the accepted answer includes a comment that reads "this doesn't work".  Especially since the code seems to rely on the thing that presumably doesn't work.

Comment: This is because I just copied the code in the question and added the if statement so it would work

Comment: I removed the misleading comment

Answer (score 0):

Define the User Model with a custom validator:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const UserModel = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11).UNSIGNED,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isUnique: (value, next) => {
        UserModel.findAll({
          where: { email: value },
          attributes: ['id'],
        })
          .then((user) => {
            if (user.length != 0)
              next(new Error('Email address already in use!'));
            next();
          })
          .catch((onError) => console.log(onError));
      },
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});

module.exports = UserModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have declared the constraint in the database, and who have generated the table models with squelize-auto, it is enough to replace :

```js
 us_mail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: 'us_mail_UNIQUE',
      validate:{
        notEmpty:{msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail pour valider le compte'},
        notNull: {msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail pour valider le compte'},
        isEmail:{msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail valide !'},
      }
    },
```

with :

```js
 us_mail: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: {name:'us_mail_UNIQUE',msg: 'Cette adresse mail est déjà utlisée'},
      validate:{
        notEmpty:{msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail pour valider le compte'},
        notNull: {msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail pour valider le compte'},
        isEmail:{msg: 'Renseigner une adresse mail valide !'},
      }
    },
```