# Sequelize validator only returning one error at a time

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Upon creating or updating items in my database using Sequelize, I find that the validator only returns a single validation error at a time.

This is not ideal, since I'd like to return all errors to the user when they submit the form that has multiple errors in it.

This is my model:

```
module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = Sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'That email is not available.'
        },
        validate: {
          isEmail: {
            args: true,
            msg: 'Please enter a valid email.'
          }
        }
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        notEmpty: true,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'That username is not available.'
        },
        validate: {
          min: {
            args: USER_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
            msg: 'Please choose a longer username.'
          },
          max: {
            args: USER_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
            msg: 'Please choose a shorter username.'
          },
          is: {
            args: /^[0-9a-zA-Z](\/?[a-zA-Z0-9-_])*\/?$/i,
            msg: 'Please enter a valid username.'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      underscored: true,
    }
  );

  return User;
};
```

This is my controller (in this case, I'm trying to update a user, say, `User 1` and modify their values for `username` and `email` which just so happen to be the same exact values for another user, say `User 2`).

```
try {
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
  if (user) {
    const updatedUser = await user.update({
      username: username || req.user.username,
      email: email || req.user.email
    });

    res.status(200).end();
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return res.status(500).send(getMappedErrors(err));
}
```

So you would expect the validator to return errors for both the `email` and `username` field since it violates the `unique` flag.

However, this is what I get in that `catch` block:

```
{ SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: That username is not available.
    at Query.formatError (/site/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:325:18)
    at query.catch.err (/site/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:86:18)
    at tryCatcher (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/site/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:763:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:734:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:716:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:101:23)
  name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
  errors:
   [ ValidationErrorItem {
       message: 'That username is not available.',
       type: 'unique violation',
       path: 'username',
       value: 'bob',
       origin: 'DB',
       instance: [user],
       validatorKey: 'not_unique',
       validatorName: null,
       validatorArgs: [] } ],
  fields: { username: 'bob' },
  parent:
   { error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_username_key"
    at Connection.parseE (/site/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:545:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/site/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:370:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/site/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:113:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:256:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:598:20)
     name: 'error',
     length: 204,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '23505',
     detail: 'Key (username)=(bob) already exists.',
     hint: undefined,
     position: undefined,
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: 'public',
     table: 'users',
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: 'users_username_key',
     file: 'nbtinsert.c',
     line: '434',
     routine: '_bt_check_unique',
     sql: 'UPDATE "users" SET "username"=\'bob\',"email"=\'me@aol.com\',"updated_at"=\'2018-03-28 19:26:27.341 +00:00\' WHERE "id" = 2' } ...
```

I truncated the rest of it, but as you can see, it only returns the error for the username. When I fix that, and then submit my form again, only then do I get the validation error for the email address.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: I am also curious if this was ever solved. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27186451/9206625) uses custom isUnique validation functions that call the find/findOne method for both username and email address. Can't this be accomplished without having to use the findOne method? I want all the errors -- not just a single error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

If you have the `allowNull:false` constraint set on a property and your field for that property is null, all validators will be skipped and a ValidationError will be thrown. So db constraints get checked first, one by one, after which the regular validation is performed, where all the errors are returned in an array as expected.

[Here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html) is a reference to the above mentioned

Comment: I am having the same issue and this is not what my issue is. I have 2 fields (username and email) that both have the not null and unique constraints and I am passing in non-null values for both when trying to create and instance of the model and I only ever get the first validation error back. As the OP mentioned, if I fix that error by changing it to an unused value, then the next validation error is returned.

Comment: Turns out in my case, the issue was misunderstanding the distinction between a validator and a constraint and expecting constraints to behave like validators (i.e. returning multiple failures, of unique constraints, in this case, in a single thrown error). For anyone else who gets tripped up by this terminology, a reasonably easy way to remember the difference is that validators happen BEFORE any SQL is executed against the DB. Constraints (unique, non null, etc.) pretty much map to their actual DB representations.

Comment: Here is the documentation that triggered the above "AHA!" moment for me: [link](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html#difference-between-validations-and-constraints)